# how to define relationship in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I want to create a form for dataentry in access. I am confused about defining the tables. I have a Student table, which includes information about student first name, last name, etc.

I have information about technical skills which has different groups (6 groups) programming, languages,banking, etc. Each group has different parts: for example, Programming has 4 parts JAVA, PHP, C, Python.

Languages also have different parts English, German, Spanish, French

Banking has these parts: Risk Management, Project Management

Each student has different skills; first student knows Java, php, German, Project Management

How many tables should I define and how go I relate them to the main Student table?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the following structure:

> **tblStudent**
>   ID (PK)
>   FirstName
>   LastName
>
> **tblStudent_Skill**
>   Student_ID (PK)(FK) 
>   Skill_ID (PK)(FK)
>
> **tblSkill**
>   ID (PK) 
>   SkillName
>   SkillType_ID (FK)
>
> **tblSkillType** 
>   ID (PK) 
>   SkillTypeName

tblStudent - only information relating to this specific person, name, address, phone, etc.

tblStudent_Skill - linking table to deal with many-many relationship between tblStudent and tblSkill.

tblSkill - specific skills, for example PHP, English, Python, Maths, etc.

tblSkillType - category list for Skills, for example programming, languages,banking, etc.